tearDownAfterClass not being invoked with PHPUNIT 11 and LARAVEL 11
I cannot figured out why the tearDownAfterClass() is not being called.
PHPunit version:
"phpunit/phpunit": "^11.2"

Laravel version:
  "laravel/framework": "^11.10"

Composer Autoload:
"autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },

My code:

<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\Models\Patient;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase;

class PatientTest extends TestCase
{
    protected $patientData;
    protected $client;
    protected $headers;
    protected $baseEndpoint;

    /**
     * This method is used to set up the test environment before each test
     */
    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $user = 'dummy';
        $pass = 'dummy';
        $base64Credential = base64_encode("{$user}:{$pass}");

        $this->headers = [
            'Authorization' => "Basic {$base64Credential}",
        ];

        $this->baseEndpoint = 'api/v1/patient';

        $this->patientData = [
            'doc' => '74308804019',
            'name' => 'John Doe',
        ];
    }

    public static function tearDownAfterClass(): void
    {
        parent::tearDownAfterClass();
        $p = Patient::where('email', 'valid@example.com')->delete();
        $u = User::where('email', 'valid@example.com')->delete();

        dump("Patients deleted: " . $p);
        dump("Users deleted: " . $u);
    }

    public function testRouteRequiresAuthentication()
    {
        $response = $this->postJson($this->baseEndpoint, []);

        $response->assertStatus(404);
    }
}

I have executed the test case with --debug and the tearDownAfterClass is not being called
vendor/bin/phpunit tests/Feature/Api/Company/Patient/PatientTest.php --debug

output:
PHPUnit Started (PHPUnit 11.2.6 using PHP 8.3.8 (cli) on Linux)
Test Runner Configured
Bootstrap Finished (/var/www/medico24hs.com.br/vendor/autoload.php)
Test Suite Loaded (1 test)
Event Facade Sealed
Test Runner Started
Test Suite Sorted
Test Runner Execution Started (1 test)
Test Suite Started (Tests\Feature\PatientTest, 1 test)
Test Preparation Started (Tests\Feature\PatientTest::testRouteRequiresAuthentication)
Before Test Method Called (Tests\Feature\PatientTest::setUp)
Before Test Method Finished:
- Tests\Feature\PatientTest::setUp
Test Prepared (Tests\Feature\PatientTest::testRouteRequiresAuthentication)
Test Passed (Tests\Feature\PatientTest::testRouteRequiresAuthentication)
After Test Method Called (Tests\Feature\PatientTest::tearDown)
After Test Method Finished:
- Tests\Feature\PatientTest::tearDown
Test Finished (Tests\Feature\PatientTest::testRouteRequiresAuthentication)
Test Suite Finished (Tests\Feature\PatientTest, 1 test)
Test Runner Execution Finished
Test Runner Finished
PHPUnit Finished (Shell Exit Code: 0)

Does anyone figured out why the tearDownAfterClass() is being called?
Thanks.

This output doesn't match the test class you posted -- the debug says it ran method testSuccessfulPatientCreation but in the code it's testRouteRequiresAuthentication. And your namespace is Tests\Feature but your command invocation references a file in tests/Feature/Api/Company/Patient. It looks like you're not running the file you think you're running.

@AlexHowansky, I removed some parts of the code because they contain sensitive information.
Now I created a new test and got the same result. I updated the question and included all the code, Thanks for the point.

Likely not your issue, just a comment: We normally place the call to parent::tearDownAfterClass(); at the end of the teardown method (similar to placing the call to a parent::setUp* at the beginning) to have set-up and tear-down in a symmetry extending TestCases.

When I read the PHPUnit test-code right (https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/16df8001b8f2db2c723ea0f4d351b8363592c003/tests/end-to-end/event/template-methods-isolation.phpt#L52) there should be some output like After Last Test Method Called (<classname>::tearDownAfterClass) and more. That PHPTest is with invocation parameters, I'd suggest you make use of them and specifically have the command-line in your question as well to show how you invoke phpunit.
